# Which font has been used in the attached picture of the resume?

Tags: fonts, resume

I am trying to compile a perfect cv with latex and I liked the CV format in the picture which I found on the internet. Can someone guess what the font style is and which compiler would be the best option?

[image: hed]

Comment: as always if you have the pdf of that document you can get a list of fonts used, you do not need to ask people to guess

Comment: I do not have the pdf. I found this picture in google images.

Comment: using a monospace font seems a very odd choice.

Comment: It looks like Consolas